# How a django channel websocket middleware can receive message

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

How a middleware can read all the websocket message ?
From my understanding a django-channel middleware is like https://github.com/django/channels/blob/2a98606c1e0600cbae71ae1f02f31aae5d01f82d/channels/middleware.py.

```
    async def coroutine_call(self, inner_instance, scope, receive, send):
        """
        ASGI coroutine; where we can resolve items in the scope
        (but you can't modify it at the top level here!)
        """
        await inner_instance(receive, send)
```

I know that if I call `await receive()` instead of `await inner_instance(receive, send)`, I will get a websocket message, but in this case the websocket handler will not work anymore.

How can a `coroutine_call` can receive the websocket message but also forward it to the next websocket middleware or handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the middleware to intercept the message it need to intercept the `receive` and `send` queues.

here is an example of a complex middleware that does this https://github.com/hishnash/channelsmultiplexer/blob/master/channelsmultiplexer/demultiplexer.py.

A simpler version of this would be:

```py
class _InterceptionMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, application_cls, scope):
        self.application = application_cls(scope)


    async def __call__(self, receive, send):
        self.downstream_send = send

        # create a Queue for the upstream consumer to read messages from
        self.upstream_receive_queue = asyncio.Queue()

        # create a Queue for the upstream consumer to write messages to
        self.upstream_send_queue = asyncio.Queue()

        # pipe messages being sent to the upstream consumer to your interceptor method
        receiver = await_many_dispatch([receive], self.my_receive_interceptor_method)

        # pipe messages being sent buy the upstream consumer to your interceptor method
        sender = await_many_dispatch(
            [self.upstream_send_queue.get],
            self.my_send_interceptor_method
        )

        # set up an asyncio task to handle these pipes
        receiver_task = asyncio.create_task(receiver)
        sender_task = asyncio.create_task(sender)

        # create an asyncio task for the upstream consumer
        upstream_task = asyncio.create_task(
            # pass the `get` and `put` methods of your upstream send and receive queues
            self.application(self.upstream_receive_queue.get, self.upstream_send_queue.put)
        )

        # await it all
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [upstream_task, receiver_task, sender_task],
            # if any of them fail stop
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
        )
        for task in [upstream_task, receiver_task, sender_task]:
            if not task.dont():
                # we need to cancel this task.
                task.cancel()
                try:
                    await task
                except CancelledError:
                    # we expect this error
                    pass


    async def my_receive_interceptor_method(self, msg):
        # your interception code
        await self.upstream_receive_queue.put(msg)


    async def my_send_interceptor_method(self, msg):
        # your interception code
        await self.downstream_send(msg)


def InterceptionMiddleware(application_cls):
    return functools.partial(_InterceptionMiddleware, application_cls)
```